How do I merge logs in Datadog for flask.send_static_file and /<path:filename>?
My app uses Flask and I've been accessing random paths to test my 404 logic (eg http://url.com/asdf). All works as expected, but I noticed that in Datadog, I'd get two errors for hitting a 404. One from flask.send_static_file, and one from /<path:filename>.
The way I understand it, there's one error for Flask trying to access a static file (even though it doesn't exist), and one error for the routing. Let me know if this assumption isn't correct.
To fix this, I added an error handler in my code:
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
  error_id = str(uuid4())[:6]
  app.logger.warning(f"404 error: {error}", extra={"errorId": error_id})
  return f"errorId={error_id}", 404

I thought the error handler in my code would consolidate these two errors in Datadog, but I'm still seeing both errors logged. Any thoughts how I could merge these two logs since they're essentially logging the same thing? Thanks in advance for the help.
